# BiometricPrompt по отпечатку пальцев без диалогового окна

Tags: android, kotlin, аутентификация, fingerprint

`FingerprintManager - deprecated java`.
Я использовал `BiometricPrompt`:

```
if (canAuthenticateWithBiometrics()) {
        val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

        val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(this, executor, object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {

            override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                TODO("Called when an unrecoverable error has been encountered and the operation is complete.")
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                TODO("Called when a biometric is recognized.")
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                TODO("Called when a biometric is valid but not recognized.")
            }
        })

        val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("Set the title to display.")
                .setSubtitle("Set the subtitle to display.")
                .setDescription("Set the description to display")
                .setNegativeButtonText("Negative Button")
                .build()

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
    } else {
        showlog("canAuthenticateWithBiometrics", "false")
    }
```

В итоге поверх `Activity` у меня в `onCreate` создаётся `BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()`.

Первый вопрос: Как использовать `BiometricPrompt` без `BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()`, т.е. в `onCreate - Activity`, инициализировать `BiometricPrompt`, дальнейшие действие по итогу `callback`(поменять свой `imageFinger` и `mgsTextViewFinger`)?

Второй вопрос:  как использовать только `FingerPrint`, т.е. если в настройках телефона предпочитаемый способ не по отпечатку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понял о чем вы, какой `dialog`? Если используете `androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt`, то все будет работать и на API до 28.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, поправил...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BiometricPrompt` придумали чтобы унифицировать UI.

Таким образом Google заставляет вас использовать стандартный диалог для запроса отпечатка пальца и в дальнейшем с распознаванием лица.
Советую вам пересмотреть подход в приложении и отказаться от собственного диалога.

Если все-таки решитесь оставить свое UI, то только через *deprecated* `FingerprintManager`, пока его совсем не вырежут.
Но думаю, это произойдет не скоро, его только в API 28 обьявили *deprecated*.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а как на счет второго вопроса?

Comment: Если в настройках нет отпечатка, то так вы им воспользуетесь? Если я правильно вас понял. Лучше отдельно его задайте и больше деталей.

Comment: Тестовый смартфон samsun s8, у него же несколько :  - По лицу, по Радужки и по Отпечатку. Вопрос, как правильно настроить biometricPrompt.authenticate только по отпечатку,  если по умолчанию у пользователя стоит по Радужке (или по лицу), заранее спасибо

Comment: Наверное никак, это отдано на выбор системе.